# Integral of a function which yields a hyper-geometric function

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals, hypergeometric-function

Note that $n$ is an arbitrary constant.
$$
\int(\sin^n(x))dx
$$
I start by using the obvious integrating by parts and get:
$$
\frac{d}{dx}[x\sin^n(x)] = \sin^n(x) + nx\sin^{n-1}(x)\cos(x)
$$

$$
x\sin(x) = \int(\sin^n(x))dx + n \int(x\sin^{n-1}(x)\cos(x))dx
$$

$$
\int(\sin^n(x))dx = x\sin(x) - n \int(x\sin^{n-1}(x)\cos(x))dx
$$
I tried to integrate using the knowledge I know but got nowhere fast, I checked wolframalpha expecting it to be something obvious but got
$$
n \int(x\sin^{n-1}(x)\cos(x))dx \\
= n\left(\frac{\sin^{n}(x)(x+\cot(x)\cdot{}_2F_{1}\left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1-n}{2};\frac{3}{2};\cos^{2}(x)\right)\sin^2(x)^{\frac{1}{2} - \frac{n}{2}}}{n}\right)+c
$$

which I simplified down to
$$
= x\sin^n(x) + \sin^{n-1}(x) \sin^{1-n}(x)\cos(x) \cdot {}_2F_1\left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1-n}{2};\frac{3}{2};\cos^2(x)\right)+c
$$

$$
=x\sin^n(x) + \cos(x)\cdot {}_2F_1\left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1-n}{2};\frac{3}{2};\cos^2(x)\right) +c
$$
But what I am oblivious to is the process that WolframAlpha took to get the integral of $x\sin^{n-1}(x)\cos(x)$. What steps were taken and where do I go to learn these steps?

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but it would be more natural to start out with $u=\sin^{n-1}x, dv=\sin x dx$.

Comment: Given the fact that you are only interested in definite integrals of powers of the sine function, see [Wallis' integrals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wallis'_integrals). Furthermore, the definite integral of the exponential of the sine function is expressible in terms of [Bessel I functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *what I am oblivious to is the process that WolframAlpha took to get the integral*

That's OK, because there is nothing either helpful or spectacular about that process. Basically, he interprets the sine function as $\sqrt{1-\cos^2x}$, and expands the integrand using the [binomial series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series), then switches the order of summation and integration, and reparses the whole expression in terms of [hypergeometric functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_function). But this is merely a question of changing one notation into another; it does not help at all in establishing meaningful results, relations, and identities involving the initial integral. What is helpful, however, is understanding the fact that all natural powers of the sine and cosine functions can be rewritten as a [linear combination](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Power-reduction_formula) of terms of the form $\sin kx$ and $\cos px$, whose integration then becomes trivial.

Comment: But the result is confusing, since the function $e^(sin(x))$ is always positive and when you simplify the integral you get 

$$
\int(sin^n(x))dx = -cos(x)*\sum_{a=0}^{\infty}[(\frac{(\frac{1}{2})_a (\frac{1-n}{2})_a}{(\frac{3}{2})_a})*\frac{(\cos(x))^{2a}}{a!}]
$$
this result then means that the result of the integral will be negative if cos(x)>0, i don't know if i'm just having brain fog or something but that seems a bit odd to me.

Comment: @EricLawson: Where did the $e^{\sin x}$ come from?

Comment: whoops, that was another topic that i am also trying to just explore, nothing to do with what we are talking about. but your explanation is very insightful and isn't what i am questioning, im just trying to interpret the result

Comment: another thing which is also bothering me and is why i probably put $e^{sin(x)}$ is since
$$
e^{sin(x)} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{sin^n(x)}{n!}
$$

i am going to attempt to say that

$$
\int(e^{sin(x)})dx = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{\int(sin^n(x))dx}{n!}
$$
which feels wrong, would this be a correct way to do this or is this just wrong?

Comment: @EricLawson: Let me guess: You initially had $\displaystyle\int_a^be^{\sin x}dx$, which you approached by expanding the integrand into its well-known Taylor series, then switched the order of summation and integration. Okay: So far, so good. Now, you notice that some of these terms might sometimes be negative, and this troubles you. But it shouldn't. Just expand $e^{-t}$ into its Taylor series: “Half” of the terms there will be negative, but the result is still positive.

Comment: this is what i see:

Comment: when i took the integral of $e^{sin(x)}$ from $0$ to $2 \pi $ i got
$2 \pi * I_{0}(1)$

but when i checked the series gives only negatives, am i doing something wrong?

Comment: @Eric Lawson: The integral is definitely positive, and your approach is correct: There are no contradictions here. However, I think that either you've made some trivial errors in computations, or are otherwise under the misguided impression that just because something has a minus sign in front of it, then it is also necessarily negative.

Comment: your assumption is probably correct, to be honest i have never taken a class that would cover this or anything like this, i have no prior exposure to this function and its properties, Is there anywhere in specific you could direct me so that i can expand my knowledge on these functions? Thank you for your help by the way.

Comment: @EricLawson: Neither have I ! :-$)$ [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_function) and [Wolfram MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunction.html) offer plenty of introductory information, whereas [NIST DLMF](http://dlmf.nist.gov) goes into much more detail.